# FFT with CUDA on same data gives different results each time?

Tags: c++, cuda, fft

Why is it that when using CUDA, if I perform a FFT with a size of 1 million, I get somewhat subtly different results every time?

My hardware has the Fermi architecture.

Comment: This is interesting. Can you post some code to show us what you are doing ?

Comment: Most likely because you're doing something somewhat subtly different every time. Show us a minimal example which exhibits this problem.

Comment: In addition to posting some code, you need to describe "subtly different" more precisely.

Comment: I didn't know we now have quantum computers now. Wow!

Comment: Perhaps you are using uninitialized variables or arrays that have random content in them before your FFT is run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might have an easy answer. CUDA programs frequently use the float variable type, as it can be considerably faster than double. The order in which operations are evaluated can significantly affect the final value of a floating point computation; this isn't unique to CUDA, but you might notice the effects particularly acutely since it is such a massively parallel paradigm (and with parallelism comes nondeterminism, at least when doing things like global reductions).

EDIT: Just to be clear, it is a necessary (though insufficient) condition that CUDA not guarantee that the same kernel will be executed in the same order across several executions. If CUDA does guarantee this, then it should not be possible for the order in which arithmetic operations are executed to vary from run to run, and as such, one would not expect to see different values for the same floating-point computation.

Here is a simple C program demonstrating the above claim. Try the code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   float a = 100.0f, b = 0.00001f, c = 0.00001f;

   printf("a + b + c = %f\n", a + b + c);
   printf("b + c + a = %f\n", b + c + a);
   printf("a + b + c == b + c + a ? %d\n", (a + b + c) == (b + c + a));

   return 0;
}
```

on Linux and see what you get (I'm using 64-bit RHEL 6 and gcc version 4.4.4-13). My output is the following:

```
[user@host directory]# gcc add.c -o add
[user@host directory]# ./add
a + b + c = 100.000015
b + c + a = 100.000023
a + b + c == b + c + a ? 0
```

EDIT: Note that while this program may suggest that the underlying issue is that floating-point addition is non-commutative, it is actually the case that floating-point addition is non-associative (since C evaluates addition operations from left to right, it just so happens that the first addition is performed as (a + b) + c and the second is performed as (b + c) + a). The reason for non-associativity is that floating-point representations can represent only finitely many significant digits (in base 2, but the discussion for a base-10 system is essentially equivalent). For instance, if only three significant digits can be represented, we get (100 + 0.5) + 0.5 = 100 + 0.5 = 100, whereas 100 + (0.5 + 0.5) = 100 + 1 = 101. In the first case, the intermediate result 100 + 0.5 must be truncated (or rounded up, possibly) since it is impossible to represent the intermediate value 100.5 with only three significant digits.

There are a number of important implications of this phenomenon; for instance, you will get a more accurate answer by adding numbers in increasing order of size (exponent). The real take-away is that you shouldn't expect the results to be identical unless the computations are being performed in the same order, which may be hard to guarantee using CUDA on a real GPU.

Comment: How would this explain variation from run to run on the same input data, other requiring than the hardware randomly reordering execution from run to run? In my experience, while the execution order is not determinable a priori, the hardware doesn't randomize execution order of the same code.

Comment: @talonmies It wasn't my impression that CUDA guarantees that you will get the same execution order from run to run. While it may not (intentionally) randomize execution, it might be subject to some kind of interference or something. If CUDA does provide such a guarantee, then I would agree that this answer is incorrect, and will remove it.

Comment: It's possible that the first issued block might be issued to different multiprocessor each time, and if there are an uneven number of blocks across multiprocessors, then the execution order could vary slightly between runs.  If atomics are involved, and memory addresses vary across runs, that might change execution order more.  BTW @Patrick87, to make your explanation of floating point execution variance truly correct, you may want to point out that the real reason for all this is that "floating point arithmetic is non-associative".

Comment: @Patrick87 Can you ad the part about CUDA not gauranteeing the order of execution to your original answer. It is better off there than in comments.

Comment: @harrism Yes, good point. The way I decided to present the output makes it look like it might simply be a commutative thing, while in reality it's the order in which binary operations are evaluated. I will add a note clarifying this point and explaining why it is the case that floating point addition is non-associative.

Comment: @Pavan I will add the assumption that CUDA does not guarantee computations will be performed in the same order from run to run. Good suggestion.

Comment: I edited your answer and added a link to [this white paper discussing floating point on NVIDIA GPUs](http://developer.nvidia.com/content/precision-performance-floating-point-and-ieee-754-compliance-nvidia-gpus).  Hopefully reviewers will accept the edit.